# New-AzureRmResourceGroup : 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, alm

I'm trying to create a new web app service in Azure from powershell, but running into the following error:

`New-AzureRmResourceGroup : 'this.Client.SubscriptionId' cannot be null.`

```
$webAppName = "powershelldemowebapp"
$ResourceGroupName = "PowerShellResourceGroup"          
$Location = "East Asia"

Login-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant 000000-0000-0000-0000-00000 -Credential $psCred
Get-AzureSubscription
Select-AzureSubscription  -SubscriptionId 00000-0000-0000-000-0000
New-AzureRmWebApp -Name $webAppName  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName  -Location $Location
```

Comment: If you have multiple ARM subscriptions, using `Select-AzureSubscription` you could not change the default subscription. The cmdlet only change classic subscriptions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Get-AzureSubscription` and `Select-AzureSubscription` are ASM cmdlets. I notice that you want to create a ARM webapp. If you have multiple ARM subscriptions, using `Select-AzureSubscription` you could not change the default subscription. The cmdlet only change classic subscriptions.

You need use ARM cmdlets.

`Get-AzureRmSubscription
Select-AzureRmSubscription  -SubscriptionId 00000-0000-0000-000-0000`

Comment: That explains why my subs wouldn't show... I'll give it a bash - Thanks.

Comment: I was just making sure it worked - before accepting it as the answer - all done - Thanks.

Comment: @Walter I also have the same issue as Stuart.Sklinar. Is it depends on the subscription level.My subscription details is : **Environment           : AzureCloud
Account               : abc@tenant.onmicrosoft.com
TenantId              : xxxx
SubscriptionId        :
SubscriptionName      :
CurrentStorageAccount :    **   Here I couldn't find any SubscriptionId.So is that the issue in my case?

Comment: @A A Do you ensure your subscription is based on ARM mode or ASM mode?

Comment: In my subscription, its listed - Access to Azure Active Directory. only. So I need to subscribe something more?

Comment: @AA If possible, you had better ask a new question to describe your question. Do you login on new Azure Portal or Classic Portal. If you login on new Portal and create VM in resource group. You should use cmdlet `Get-AzureRmSubscription`  and `Select-AzureRmSubscription`.

Comment: @Walter-MSFT  My issue got solved, I don't have subscription for that. Added new subscription

Comment: Can we use this same command in powershell core azure function?

Answer (score 0):

This is just building up @Shui.Sklinar's answer. Below are similar commands in [Azure CLI in powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) if anyone is using that.

1. `Get-AzSubscription` # Get all the available subscriptions under your account.
2. `Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId 00000-0000-0000-000-0000` # Select a particular subscription.